withoutGlobalScope is not working in relation hasMany in Laravel Model
My Scope:
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class InventorySeriesScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    // withoutGlobalScope(ClinicScope::class)
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $table = $model->getTable();
        $builder->where($table . '.is_used',0);
         
    }
}


InventorySeries Model where scope is used:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use App\Scopes\InventorySeriesScope;

class InventorySeries extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table="inventory_series";
    protected $primarykey="id";
    protected $guarded=['id'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new InventorySeriesScope);
    }

}


My model where i am using withoutGlobalScope:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class GatePassOutwardEntryChild extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'gatepass_outward_entry_child';
    protected $PrimaryKey = 'id';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function inventoryseries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InventorySeries','gatepass_outward_child_id','id')->withoutGlobalScope(InventorySeriesScope::class);
    }
}


My controller where I want my data withoutGlobalScope which gives data including global scope
$data['child'] = GatePassOutwardEntryChild::with('inventoryseries')->get();
dd($data['child'][0]);

In this as a result I am getting data for inventoryseries with is_used as 0 but I have some records with is_used as 0 and 1 both, I want all that records not only with 0

or add use App\Scopes\InventorySeriesScope; to your GatePassOutwardEntryChild class file

give full path in your model instead of using class like
public function inventoryseries()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InventorySeries','gatepass_outward_child_id','id')->withoutGlobalScope("App\Scopes\InventorySeriesScope");

}

It works for me !!
